# How to send Offline Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have read that it is not possible to send Push Notifications if you are offline. I'm working on an app that generates reminders at certain time. Now this app is totally offline but there is a need that if the app is closed it should still send reminder on time. This thing is only possible with `PushNotifications` as far as I've read. And `LocalNotifications` did not work if your app is not running.
So what it the way to generate offline notifications even if the app is closed?

`LocalNotification` are again not solving my problem. Because user will open the app to do settings, and once these settings are done he may not open the app again until he feels the need to change the reminder time. And app will communicate with user via notifications. So this is mandatory for me to generate notifications on the time that user sets for as long as it needs to.
Is there any way I can copy the way reminders work?

Comment: Local notifications will work if your app isn't running,but there is a limit as they how many you can schedule  at once

Comment: @Paulw11 There will be one or maximum three notifications a day. But I've read that if the app is closed (double tap the home button and then close it by swipe up) it'll not run the notifications. Is this true?

Comment: That is not true. The only issue that arises is the limit of schedules. Say you wanted 3 per day - with a limit of 20'you could only schedule the next 6 days. If the user opens your app within those 6 days then you can schedule some more, but if they don't then your app will eventually stop notifying

Comment: @Paulw11 then how does the alarm works in iPhone? Is there any way we can trigger custom alarm that? It's also like a offline notification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local notification while app not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732784/local-notification-while-app-not-running)

Comment: Native apps, like the alarm app, are not subject to the same restrictions as other apps. You could add your reminders to the user's calendar with a reminder, but they wouldn't be able to launch your app from the reminder

Comment: @Paulw11 right! So at the moment `LocalNotifications` is the best option I have.